# PHP does not retrieve MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying retrieve the values of columns "v162" and "v164" from a MySQL database.  It connects just fine, but does not retrieve the information from the two columns.

The row of the columns I am trying to retrieve (the one that matches the title) are both TINYINT(1) values as follows:

v162 = 1

v164 = 0

Here's the code I have currently:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE title = '$title'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if ($row["v162"] == '1') {
           echo '<div id="162link' . $i . '">1.6.2</div>'; 
        }
        if ($row["v164"] == '1') {
           echo '<div id="164link' . $i . '">1.6.4</div>';
        }
      $i++;
    }

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

I have previously asked for correction of the code, which has some more severe errors, now I just need the data to actually be retrieved successfully.

Comment: First debugging step: use `var_dump($row);` in the loop to see if your actual values match your expectation.

Comment: Where are you setting the value for `$title`?

Comment: @mario Changed the `SELECT *` to `SELECT v162, v164` and it returned "NULL array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "0" }"  So the "v162" part should echo correctly but not the "v164," which is what I would like.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan The code above is in a file that is included (`include('LocationHere');`) in another PHP file (the one that is actually shown to visitors).  At the top of that file, `$title` is set.

Comment: Well, when your `$row` contains `[0]` and `[1]` as keys, how did you expect accessing it with `$row[v162]` or `$row[v164]` to work?

Comment: @mario Thanks, keys were wrong as you said.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query fails because of an error your script will do nothing, but you won't see the error. If it fails to find a match then again your script will do nothing. Add some code to check the return value of your query.

Try

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error());  // Quit with error if query fails.

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {   // Display something informative if nothing is found.
   echo '<div>No matches found</div>'; 
} else {   
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if ($row["v162"] == '1') {
           echo '<div id="162link' . $i . '">1.6.2</div>'; 
        }
        if ($row["v164"] == '1') {
           echo '<div id="164link' . $i . '">1.6.4</div>';
        }
      $i++;
    }

    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're doing doesn't work for you then look at the documentation.

[Here's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) an example of how you should init your connection.

- Doesn't matter if you say it works, you have to be 110% sure.

[Here's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1631) an example of how to select data with mysqli.

- The way you do it is different from the documentation; a hint that you may be doing it wrong
- You don't actually check if anything is fetched at all; use the information at hand to help you.

If you do exactly the same as the documentation declares and still you're having problems (and you've actually wrapped an exception handler around the connection) then come back to us.